# Obtain a "list" of stored procedures which include INSERTs without naming the columns involved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures

As part of some enhancement, a new column has been added to over 750 tables. Now my problem is within almost 3000+ of stored procedures, some old INSERTs do not name columns.

Is there any way I can get a "list" of all the stored procedures that are inserting without column names?

I have tried:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%insert into%' 
AND definition NOT LIKE '%) value%'
AND definition NOT LIKE '%)%' + CHAR(10) + '%value%'
AND definition NOT LIKE '%)%' + CHAR(13) + '%value%'
AND definition LIKE '%value%'
```

But it's still misses a lot.

P.S. - The above query is returning Insert Into (ColumnNames) SELECT scenario too , which i don't want.

Comment: Can you give some examples of ones that it misses?

Comment: Yeah, Like - `INSERT INTO TABLENAME SELECT FROM TABLE`

Comment: The relevant keyword is `VALUES`, not `VALUE`, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a DMV called [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql). It returns a column `is_insert_all` documented thus

> 1 = The object is used in an INSERT statement without a column list (object-level only).

This seems to be what you're looking for.

Here's an example of it in practice. First we'll create a simple one-column table

```
drop table if exists dbo.T1;
go
create table dbo.T1(c int);
```

Now two stored procedures, one references columns explicitly the other does not.

```
create or alter procedure dbo.p_named
as
begin
    insert dbo.T1(c)  -- columns are listed
    select 1;
end
go

create or alter procedure dbo.p_not_named
as
begin
    insert dbo.T1   -- no column list
    select 2;
end
go
```

The DMV is a table-valued function. As such it can be invoked using the [CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#using-apply) syntax. The names of procedures to pass to this function can be obtained from the catalog view [sys.procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql). The documentation for this DMV states

> schema_name is required when the referencing class is OBJECT.

We can get the schema name using a built-in metadata function handily called [SCHEMA_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/schema-name-transact-sql). Putting it all together we get

```
select
    p.name, is_insert_all -- other columns exist
from sys.procedures as p
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id), '.', p.name), 'OBJECT');
```

Which returns this

```
name          is_insert_all
------------- -------------
p_named       0
p_named       0
p_not_named   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this query will help you to find the SPs having `INSERT` statement without specifying columns in it.

First and second steps have sample table and stored procedure.

Executing 3rd and 4th steps together returns the SPs.

```
1.-----------Sample Table
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Employee
(
EmpId int identity(1,1),
EmpName varchar(16)
);

2.-----------Sample Stored Procedures
CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_Without_Columns_VALUES
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tbl_Employee
    VALUES('Rajesh Ranjan');
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_Without_Columns_SELECT
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Tbl_Employee
        SELECT TOP 1 EmpName FROM TblEmployee
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_With_Columns_VALUES
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Tbl_Employee(EmpName)
        VALUES('Alok Kuwnar')
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_With_Columns_SELECT
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Tbl_Employee(EmpName)
        SELECT'Aaron Bertrand'
END
```

--3---------Take object definition (REPLACE space, tab and enter with '') into temporary table (except all system objects)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SpDefinition
CREATE TABLE #SpDefinition
(
SPName VARCHAR(128),
Definition NVARCHAR(4000)
)
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO #SpDefinition(SPName,Definition)
SELECT
        OBJECT_NAME(SM.OBJECT_ID) SPName
        ,REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(SM.DEFINITION,
                                    '"',''), --Removing double quote
                            ']',''), --Removing closing square bracket
                        '[',''), --Removing oppenign square bracket
                    ' ',''), --Removing space
                '   ',''), --Removing Tab
            CHAR(13),''), --Removing enter
        CHAR(10),'') Definition
FROM
        SYS.SQL_MODULES SM
        INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS O
        ON O.Object_id=SM.Object_id
WHERE
        O.Schema_Id NOT IN (2,3,4,16384,16385,16386,16387,16389,16390,16391,16392,16393)
```

--4---------Find the stored procedures not using column names within INSERT statement

```
DECLARE @StoredProcedures TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(128))

DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(24)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SearchValue1 NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @SearchValue2 NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @SearchValue3 NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @SearchValue4 NVARCHAR(256)

DECLARE Cur_GetTable CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID), SchemaName,REPLACE([Name],' ','') TableName FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE [TYPE] IN ('U','V')  --For user defined objects only
OPEN Cur_GetTable
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_GetTable INTO @SchemaName,@TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @SearchValue1 = '%INSERTINTO'+@TableName+'VALUES%' --Without Schema
    SET @SearchValue2 = '%INSERTINTO'+@TableName+'SELECT%' --Without Schema
    SET @SearchValue3 = '%INSERTINTO'+@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName+'VALUES%' --With Schema
    SET @SearchValue4 = '%INSERTINTO'+@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName+'SELECT%' --With Schema

        INSERT INTO @StoredProcedures([Name])
        SELECT SPName FROM #SpDefinition
        WHERE
                (Definition LIKE @SearchValue1
                OR Definition LIKE  @SearchValue2
                OR Definition LIKE  @SearchValue3
                OR Definition LIKE  @SearchValue4
                )

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_GetTable INTO @SchemaName,@TableName
END

CLOSE Cur_GetTable
DEALLOCATE Cur_GetTable
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT [Name] FROM @StoredProcedures
```

Results to

```
----------------------------

Prc_Without_Columns_VALUES

Prc_Without_Columns_SELECT

(2 rows affected)
```

Thanks!